# Where is the second season of "Danna ga Nani o Itteiru ka Wakaranai Ken", chronologically compared to the first?

Tags: danna-wakaranai-ken

In season 1 episode 13 "Me, Her, and Another" (the last episode), Kaoru learns she is pregnant.

However, the second season makes no reference to this (supposedly huge) factor in their relationship.

Is there any hint where the two seasons are chronologically (from the manga, for example)?

Answer (score 5):

The second season interleaves with the events in the first season.

On the title card roughly in the middle of each episode, it shows the episode number and where it relates to the first season in parentheses below it.

- Episode 1 is 7.5
- Episode 2 is 9.5
- Episode 3 is 8.5
- Episode 4 is 11.5
- Episode 5 is 12.5

Screenshot from Episode 3:

[image: Season 2 Episode 3 0:42 title card]

Screenshot from Episode 4:

[image: Season 2 Episode 4 1:37 title card]

Comment: Wow that's just weird. I think I'll rewatch the show in the right order then.